# How do I require the user to always enter his passphrase/use fingerprint when logging into my Android app?

Tags: android

Given that my app contains very sensitive information, I want to require the user to enter his passphrase whenever he enters the app.

Is there a straightforward way to implement this?

Comment: instead of storing login related data in sharedprefs etc , save them in application class variable so data will only be there until user wont kill the app .

Comment: Use `KeyguardManager` and methods like `isDeviceSecure()` and `createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent()`. See [this sample activity](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/FINAL/DeviceAuth/SecureCheck/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/auth/check/MainActivity.java).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to always enter credentials, simply don't store them in a persisted fashion or use AccountManager. Create an in-memory singleton to hold them for the duration of the session (or as long as you want) and then tear it down manually or let it die with the process.